# What is the message when it is building on Golang?

Tags: go

When I build source on Golang, I saw the warning message, but I couldn't find answer about it.

```
$ go build --mod=mod -o main main.go
# command-line-arguments
ld: warning: -no_pie is deprecated when targeting new OS versions
```

- specs
  version : go version go1.18 darwin/amd64
  os : Monterey 12.6
  build command : go build --mod=mod -o [binary name] main.go

Comment: If you're asking what that specific flag is, you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50615370/9335036

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a known issue. See [Github](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/55058) for more information.

As a workaround you can pass the `-buildmode=pie` flag to your `go build` command.

Answer (score 1):

From GitHub: [link](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/54482#issuecomment-1251124908)

```
There are a few options:

- wait for the next Go 1.19.x and 1.18.x releases, probably early next month
- build Go from the master branch
- pass -buildmode=pie flag to go build and go test for a workaround
- use older version of the system linker
```